# How to stage the files to the local git repository where file names has space in them?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-add, git-stage

I have 2 files locally: File 1.txt and File 2.txt.

When I stage the files with the command `git add File 2.txt`, it is giving me the below error:

> fatal: pathspec 'File' did not match any files

[image: git stage file error]

Comment: You need to first learn the syntax of your shell. I don't do Windows so I'm not familiar with either the COMSPEC shell (DOS shell) or the PowerShell but on most Unix shells (bash, zsh, tcsh etc.) you can encapsulate a space with either quotes: `git add "File 2.txt"` or with a backslash `git add File\  2.txt`. I'm not sure if either will work with COMSPEC or PowerShell because as I've said, I don't use Windows however you can use bash on Windows by installing gitbash

Comment: to avoid a lot of problems don't use spaces in file/directory names, always

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+space+filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself by referring the [article](https://www.nobledesktop.com/learn/git/stage-commit-files#:%7E:text=%27git%20add%27%20command%20is%20used,git%20reset%20HEAD%20%5Bfilename%5D%27.) in Noble desktop Blog.

The answer is:

> If the file name/path has a space, wrap it in quotes(Single/double).

Command:

```
git add 'File 2.txt'
```